# How to fix IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing

I'm mostly a Java user, however for my GCSE I have to use Python.
I was mucking around making an algorithm to find palindromic numbers.
The code is a big mess, as I .One- haven't yet entirely figured out Python syntax. and .Two- Haven't shortened the algorithm, except making it start from the higher number and work backwards.
The code is as following for python 3.4.1:

```
print("This program will find the nearest palindromic number to a given value.")
countN = input("Input a number above 0 to find the nearest palindromic number")
countN = str(countN)
nl = len(countN) # Number length
pf = 0 # Palindrome found
while(pf == 0 and int(countN)>=0): #While no palindrome found and count is bigger than 0
 ep = nl # end pointer
sp = -1 # start pointer
 while(int(ep) >= sp):
if(int(countN[ep]) == int(countN[sp])):
 ep = ep-1
 sp = sp+1
print(count + " is a palindrome.")
 pf = 1
else:
print(count + " is not a palindrome.")
countN = countN - 1
```

I was just thinking the changing the pointers bit, should it be separate from the IF statement?

Anyway the error I am running into is as follows:

```
>>> 
This program will find the nearest palindromic number to a given value.
Input a number above 0 to find the nearest palindroic number99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Computer science/palindrome finder.py", line 10, in <module>
    if(int(countN[ep]) == int(countN[sp])):
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Please note: I have searched here for an answer, part of the reason there are str() and int()'s everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
nl = len(countN)  # this is the length of your string
```

Then you say

```
ep = nl 
...
int(countN[ep]...
```

If you have a string of length 10, the valid indexes are `0` to `9`, so `10` is out of range.

The quickest fix would be to change your initializations outside the `while` loop to.

```
ep = nl -1
sp = 0
```

However, to solve such a problem I would just do

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    text = str(x)     # Convert number to string
    return text == text[::-1]   # Compare string to reversed string

>>> isPalindrome(123454321)
True

>>> isPalindrome(12345)
False
```